# initializing a dynamic array to 0?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main()
{
    int arraySize;
    int arrayMain[arraySize-1];
    cout << "\n\nEnter Total Number of Elements in Array.\n\n";
    cin >> arraySize;
    arrayMain[arraySize-1]={0};
    cout <<"\n\n" <<arrayMain;
    return 0;
}
```

my compiler freezes when I compile the above code. I am confused on how to set a dynamic array to 0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vec(arraySize-1);
```

Your code is invalid because 1) `arraySize` isn't initialized and 2) you can't have variable length arrays in C++. So either use a vector or allocate the memory dynamically (which is what `std::vector` does internally):

```
int* arrayMain = new int[arraySize-1] ();
```

Note the `()` at the end - it's used to value-initialize the elements, so the array will have its elements set to 0.

Comment: i have to use in int array

Comment: How about `std=c++11`?

Answer (score 9):

if you want to initialize whole array to zero do this ,

```
int *p = new int[n]{0};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a valid answer. Because, it just initializes the very first element of array to the value in brackets. For example 

int *p = new int[n]{1};
will set just the p[0] to 1.

Comment: This just initializes the first element of array to the number specified

Comment: Yes @shiwang You are right when you want to initialize other then 0. But for 0 this will works :)

Answer (score 5):

If you must use a dynamic array you can use value initialization (though `std::vector<int>` would be the recommended solution):

```
int* arrayMain = new int[arraySize - 1]();
```

Check the result of input operation to ensure the variable has been assigned a correct value:

```
if (cin >> arraySize && arraySize > 1) // > 1 to allocate an array with at least
{                                      // one element (unsure why the '-1').
    int* arrayMain = new int[arraySize - 1]();

    // Delete 'arrayMain' when no longer required.
    delete[] arrayMain;
}
```

Note the use of `cout`:

```
cout <<"\n\n" <<arrayMain;
```

will print the address of the `arrayMain` array, not each individual element. To print each individual you need index each element in turn:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) std::cout << arrayMain[i] << '\n';
```